# Set left margin to Zebra printer while printing text file from android app

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

I am trying to print a single image to a zebra printer(RW220) from android.

But image get cut on the left hand side(about 50 dp),I am unable to set the left margin from android code.

However,I came to know that zebra printer uses CPCL commands to set the margins but i don't know how/where to use this commands.

Please help me if anyone have set the left margin while printing image using  zebra printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using cpcl to desing a ticket, so i have been reading the cpcl programmin manual, please check the nex left margin command.

**LMARGIN** Command
The LMARGIN command sets the left margin in line print mode. Instead of issuing several X commands or inserting spaces, the LMARGIN command moves everything over the number of dots you choose.

Format:

! U1 LMARGIN {dots to offset from left}
This function can be used with the PAGE-WIDTH command. LMARGIN will move the left margin over the
set number of dots from the automatically calculated side of the paper.

for example: 
  **! U1 LMARGIN 15**

check the page 33 of this manual: http://www.maxatec-europe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/CPCL_Commands_Manual_1.1.pdf

hope this help !

Comment: can we print table like structure using CPCL?